# How to perform a click in a timer

Tags: c#

I am creating a music player in c#. I've created a trackbar and a timer so that is can select different parts of a song. Now I want to play the next song when the trackbar has reached the end of the song by performing a click on a button that plays the next song. But it does not work and I can't see why. Here's my code:

```
    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        trackBar1.Maximum = (int)wp.currentMedia.duration;
        trackBar1.Value = (int)wp.controls.currentPosition;
        var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(trackBar1.Value);
        var timeend = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(trackBar1.Maximum);
        label2.Text = timespan.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        label3.Text = timeend.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        if (trackBar1.Value == trackBar1.Maximum)
        {
            button3.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which Timer class do you use?

Comment: This is the definition of my timer: Timer t;

Comment: Yes, but what's its namespace? `System.Threading`, `System.Timers` or `System.Windows.Forms`?
What happens if you put a breakpoint on `Clicked` event and on `PerformClick()`?

Comment: The namespace is System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: Did you try to set breakpoints as I've mentioned above?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to  work with breakpoints...